# UIWebView Mix up the loaded images in the page

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova, uiwebview

I've encountered some odd behaviour .

We've developed an hybrid IOS application that uses webview (cordova 3.7),
the application has a big catalog of assets (movies) when each asset have a poster and a title.

sometimes when the app is loaded, you can see that all the images in the page are mixed up, i mean that an asset display the right name but not the right image.

after inspecting in the safari and checking in the network area, the img requests shows the wrong picture but when i double click on the link and it opened on the chrome on the mac then i can see the right image.

a very odd bug and if some one can throw some light on it it would be awesome.
it reproduces on all ios devices. (ipad/iphone/ios7/ios8)

Thank you very much for assisting !

Comment: Have you found an resolutions for this?  We're having this issue as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, couldn't resolve this, instead what i did is to put a dummy query param in the url of the image and each time i load the app i put different query param to get image without caching. 
it comes from the cache mechanisem. Good luck !